# Formatting string not working

Tags: python, pygame

I have done some research on formatting string but it does not want to work for me. I have this

```
for i in range(0,10):
    stat = arr[i]
    highscoreText = GameFont.render('{0:12}{1:>0}'.format(stat["Name"],stat["Score"]),2,(255,255,255))
    Screen.blit(highscoreText,[50,50 + (i*30)])
```

Output: http://prntscr.com/b9abfw
The name works but I can't seem to make the Score align to the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string formatting works as expected. Try to print formatted sting in console. The problem with the font you use. See, `ll`  in `hello` take the same span as `k` below.
To solve this you have to render names and scores separately and then blit them at appropriate positions.
Or you can change the font you use to a monospace, like Courier or Dejavu mono

Answer (score 1):

String formatting assumes that you are using a monospace font. Since you have decided to use a proportional font you will need to draw as separate blocks and use the graphics routines to align each block to the right.